# SQL single query update

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update

I'm having to insert values into a new column in our database but I can't get my head around doing this in a consistent manner. There is a lot of data so doing anything manually is pretty much out of the question. Let me set the stage:

We have a table called Occurrence and a table called OccurenceBuckets where each occurrence is reference the bucket to which it has been assigned. Previously this was a one-way reference but for various reasons we have decided to add a reference back from the OccurrenceBucket to the first Occurrence (first in time, that is). The tables now look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Occurrence
  OccurrenceID uniqueidentifier,
  OccurrenceBucketID uniqueidentifier,
  OccurrenceTime datetime,
  OccurrenceMessage nvarchar
  ...other meta data...

CREATE TABLE OccurrenceBucket
  OccurrenceBucketID uniqueidentifier,
  ...other meta data...
  FirstOccurrenceID uniqueidentifier,
  FirstOccurrenceTime datetime,
  FirstOccurrenceMessage nvarchar
```

I'm looking for a way to determine the first occurrence belonging to a bucket and assigning the FirstOccurrenceID, FirstOccurrenceTime and FirstOccurrenceMessage with values from this first occurrence for all my occurrencebuckets.

Do any of you sql-fu experts out there have the time to help me out, all my attempts seen to produce incorrect or incomplete selection of occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @Occurrence TABLE(
        OccurrenceID INT,
        OccurrenceBucketID INT,
        OccurrenceTime DATETIME,
        OccurrenceMessage VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Occurrence (OccurrenceID,OccurrenceBucketID,OccurrenceTime,OccurrenceMessage)  
SELECT 1, 1, '01 Jan 2009', 'A'
INSERT INTO @Occurrence (OccurrenceID,OccurrenceBucketID,OccurrenceTime,OccurrenceMessage)  
SELECT 2, 1, '02 Jan 2009', 'B'
INSERT INTO @Occurrence (OccurrenceID,OccurrenceBucketID,OccurrenceTime,OccurrenceMessage)  
SELECT 3, 1, '03 Jan 2009', 'C'


INSERT INTO @Occurrence (OccurrenceID,OccurrenceBucketID,OccurrenceTime,OccurrenceMessage)  
SELECT 4, 2, '04 Jan 2009', 'D'
INSERT INTO @Occurrence (OccurrenceID,OccurrenceBucketID,OccurrenceTime,OccurrenceMessage)  
SELECT 5, 2, '05 Jan 2009', 'E'
INSERT INTO @Occurrence (OccurrenceID,OccurrenceBucketID,OccurrenceTime,OccurrenceMessage)  
SELECT 6, 2, '06 Jan 2009', 'F'

SELECT * FROM @Occurrence

DECLARE @OccurrenceBucket TABLE(
        OccurrenceBucketID INT,
        FirstOccurrenceID INT,
        FirstOccurrenceTime DATETIME,
        FirstOccurrenceMessage VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @OccurrenceBucket (OccurrenceBucketID) SELECT 1
INSERT INTO @OccurrenceBucket (OccurrenceBucketID) SELECT 2

SELECT * FROM @OccurrenceBucket


UPDATE  @OccurrenceBucket
SET     FirstOccurrenceID = OccurrenceID,
        FirstOccurrenceTime = OccurrenceTime,
        FirstOccurrenceMessage = OccurrenceMessage
FROM    @OccurrenceBucket oc INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  o.*
            FROM    @Occurrence o INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT  OccurrenceBucketID,
                                MIN(OccurrenceID) FirstOccurrenceID
                        FROM    @Occurrence
                        GROUP BY OccurrenceBucketID
                    ) Mins ON o.OccurrenceID = mins.FirstOccurrenceID
        ) Vals ON oc.OccurrenceBucketID = Vals.OccurrenceBucketID

SELECT * FROM @OccurrenceBucket
```

EDIT:

```
UPDATE  @OccurrenceBucket 
SET     FirstOccurrenceID = OccurrenceID, 
        FirstOccurrenceTime = OccurrenceTime, 
        FirstOccurrenceMessage = OccurrenceMessage 
FROM    @OccurrenceBucket oc INNER JOIN 
        ( 
                SELECT  o.* 
                FROM    @Occurrence o INNER JOIN 
                                ( 
                                        SELECT  OccurrenceBucketID, 
                                                        MIN(OccurrenceTime) FirstOccurrenceTime 
                                        FROM    @Occurrence 
                                        GROUP BY OccurrenceBucketID 
                                ) Mins ON o.OccurrenceTime = mins.FirstOccurrenceTime 
        ) Vals ON oc.OccurrenceBucketID = Vals.OccurrenceBucketID
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately we use uniqueidentifers for IDs so the MIN(OccurrenceID) won't work. Do you have another way for performing the select?

Comment: changed the solution, use OccurenceTime

Answer (score 1):

Well, to find the first occurrence in a bucket shouldn't the following work?

```
SELECT TOP 1
  OccurranceID, OccurranceTime, OccurranceMessage
FROM Occurance
WHERE
  OccurranceBucketID = @OccurranceBucketID
ORDER BY
  OccurranceTime ASC
```

You can assign the returned fields to variables and then update your OccurranceBucket accordingly.

<sup>NB: "occurrence" has no "a" in it.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This answer relies on the OccurrenceTime being unique for each Occurrence: -

```
update OccBuck set  
OccBuck.FirstOccurrenceID = Occ.OccurrenceID,  
OccBuck.FirstOccurrenceTime = Occ.OccurrenceTime,  
OccBuck.FirstOccurrenceMessage = Occ.OccurrenceMessage  
from  
dbo.OccurrenceBucket as OccBuck  
inner join dbo.Occurrence as Occ on OccBuck.OccurrenceBucketID = Occ.OccurrenceBucketID  
inner join (select OccurrenceBucketID,  
MIN(OccurrenceTime) as 'MinOccurrenceTime'  
from dbo.Occurrence  
group by OccurrenceBucketID) as minOcc on Occ.OccurrenceBucketID=  minOcc.OccurrenceBucketID and  
Occ.OccurrenceTime = minOcc.MinOccurrenceTime;
```